# How can I track both current and maximum values for a given statistic?

Tags: c#, game-state

In my design I have several cases where I need to track both a max value and a current value (examples include Hit Points or Movement Points).
I could track these as separate variables:

```
int HitPointsMax;
int HitPointsCurrent;
```

or as a struct:

```
public struct HitPoints {
  public int Max;
  public int Current;
}
```

So my question: **Is one of these preferable over the other, and why?**

Is there some element of efficiency? A best-practice? Is there a better option?

Comment: There is too little info given for anyone to answer. what are the use scenarios? how is other data structured?

Comment: and btw if its only for two these int they will fit in a cache line so no worries. but still too little info

Comment: In programming and life in general there is no list of correct answers. If two options seem to both do the job fine there is a good chance that it actually doesn't really matter which one you choose. Save your worry for some real problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *vast majority* of cases, your best bet is with **loose values** like this:

```
int hitPointsMax;
int hitPointsCurrent;
```

This is by far the easiest thing to think about and to modify. The "structure" (including putting the values close together in memory for performance) should be provided by whatever class (eg: `Player`) they reside in. Leave the `Player` class to be responsible for managing how the two variables relate.

This way, if the way hitpoints work changes (eg: "now player can boost their HP past its capacity", or "monsters max HP is defined by monster type lookup and doesn't change") then you haven't locked yourself into some complex structure - possibly that other code depends on - that you have to pick apart later.

---

Now, that being said, what if you've got lots of this functionality spread across your codebase, and you're finding you're getting lots of duplicated code:

The *first* thing to consider is the possibility that your (for example) `Player` and `Monster` classes should inherit from some common class like `Lifeform` or `Actor` (or be composed with that class or whatever).

If that doesn't solve the problem, if you've genuinely got identical hitpoint handling or stat-with-a-maximum handling in many disparate places, and especially if you're passing the values (current and max) around a lot as a "unit", *then* you might consider turning them into a specific struct.

If hitpoint handling is somehow "special" - perhaps you will have hitpoint-specific methods - then you may want to do this:

```
public struct HitPoints { public int max; public int current; }
```

Otherwise, if you've got stats like "hit points" and "armour points" and "movement points", with identical functionality, do something like:

```
public struct StatWithMax { public int max; public int current; }
```

And then create variables for each one:

```
StatWithMax hitPoints;
StatWithMax movementPoints;
```

(Your struct should probably start with simple public variables like that, and then add in additional functionality as it is needed.)

---

Bottom line: **It's all a matter of taste.** The overall goal should generally be to minimise the amount of coding work in the long term. Sometimes you will want to make something extremely simple and flexible; other times you'll want to impose some extra structure to reduce duplication and save work later on.

Obviously, in this particular case, the difference is insignificant. But the principles are important.

(Take a look at [this lecture](http://the-witness.net/news/2011/06/how-to-program-independent-games/) for some more thinking on the topic.)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably generalize when you can to prevent code duplication.
For instance (pseudo code):

```
class BoundedVal<class T> {

    // Normal val can be used for attributes like defense or attack
    // that are temporarily buff/debuffed
    T min, max, normal_val, val;
    void inc_val(T amount){
        val = min(max, val + amount);
    }

    void dec_val(T amount){
        val = max(min, val - amount);
        if (val == min) event_on_min();
    }
     // You can add some event too
    void event_on_min(){
        // do stuff (if ran out of xyz)
    }
}
```

This way you handle, hp, mana, stamina and what not.
Since C# does not support templates to the extent c++ does and does not allow arithmetic operators to be used with unspecified types, you will want to use a specific type where I wrote T. I would use double for flexibility unless you need fine-grained control on very large integers.

To learn more about this subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: Note that the question is tagged C#, and this is C++ code.

Comment: This _pseudocode_ is more C# than C++, particularly regarding the use of a generic-like constraint. The min/max also lacks the Math/std namespaces, which makes it rather hard to identify it as a language, particularly as it's mentioned that it's no language.

Comment: Ah, I did miss where Arthur had written "pseudo code". However this is still very close to a C++ implementation. There's a few things here that aren't idiomatic C#, and a few things that are flat-out wrong for C#.

Comment: @AndrewRussell clarified

Answer (score 0):

Arguably there are benefits to the structure. Grouping related data, and in low level languages elements of structures are kept adjacent in memory so faster access (though this is largely an "academic" performance increase - unlikely to be noticeable).

I think any efficiency would be negligible and in terms of best practice I'm sure that is completely subjective - there isn't a de facto method.

In the end it's up to you and whatever you're happiest with.

Comment: actually it's the opposite of academic. but highly depends on the application

Comment: What I meant by academic is in most applications it has little if any noticeable effect. It's like when your algorithms lecturer tells you decrementing a for loop to zero is faster than incrementing because 0==0 is faster than 2==2. It's true. It just doesn't make a difference 99% of the time

Comment: Academics usually study algorithms in asymptotically. studying algorithms memory access is usually a more practical discipline.  That was my point

Answer (score -1):

Either way would work just fine.

However, the way that I like to do it is to just have one variable with a value of the max hit points (5 in this case).

Then just subtract from that variable. And test whether it is equal to zero.

Initialization

```
int HitPoints = 5;
```

When hit is detected

```
--HitPoints;
if (HitPoints <= 0)
{
    // Do what you want to do when hit points are used up
}
```

However, there may be certain cases where you would want to store the MaxHitPoints variable anyway so either way is good.

Comment: This does not really address the question, instead it sidesteps it entirely and suggests something different. That would be fine, but the actual portion of this answer that *tries* to pertain to the question is nothing that has not already been said, and with more assertiveness.